# Concatenate formula/even the TEXTJOIN formula doesn't work properly when the format of Source cell is different than the actual value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need some help with my excel formula. I have applied the concatenate formula to a range of cells in column D, wherein the formula takes the cell values from Column B and Column C and gives the result in Column D. Here for the column B, i have changed the Format of all cells to Custom Format **"0000000000"** - 10 digit numeric format.

This is because sometimes the values in column B has only 6 or 7 numeric values. So with the format, it changes to 10 digit numeric value in column B. My problem is that - in the final concatenate result in column D, it gives the result with the 7 digit partial numeric value only. Is there anyway to get around this, so that my final result in column D will have the 10 digit number format included as well?

I have attached a screenshot for better understanding. In this screenshot below, i would like my final result in column D to be **0000351235,328451** .

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply same formatting before using concatenate or joining two values. Use `TEXT()` function to apply format. Try-

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,TEXT(B4,"0000000000"),C4)
```

Using `CONCATENATE()` function.

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(B4,"0000000000"),",",C4)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Harun. I used the Concatenate alternative - and it helped a lot.

Comment: @Kuldeep Glad to know!

Answer (score 1):

In Excel Cell number formatting is a `façade`, it stores one thing, shows us another. The cell displays one things and have another thing, so instead of applying the cell custom formatting use the same within the formula as shown in below.

[image]

---

The above screenshot shows the nuances of Excel Cell Custom Formatting, refer the formula bar and see the custom formatting applied both different. So instead of doing custom formatting apply it using formula.

---

Here are few alternatives one could try:

[image]

---

Using `BASE()` Function:

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D4</kbd>

```
=BASE(B4,10,10)&","&C4
```

---

Using `REPT()` Function:

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D5</kbd>

```
=TEXT(B5,REPT(0,10))&","&C5
```

---

Using `TEXT()` & `TEXTJOIN()` Function:

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D6</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,TEXT(B6:C6,{"0000000000","General"}))
```

---

Comment: Thanks a lot Mayukh for the explanation and the alternate ways in which i can solve my issue. This helped a lot.